Windows 11: how to manually start "welcome experience"/"let's finish setting up this device"?
in the past i think i tried to disable the "welcome experience"/"let's finish setting up this device" white screen that opens up on every major windows 11 update.
Now, whether it's enabled or disabled in my settings/registry, on every single PC reboot the welcome experience white screen pops up for a couple of seconds, then closes by itself; i don't know if it crashes or does nothing and closes itself.
It's pretty annoying, so i'd like to try to manually run that screen/program, to see what it would like for me to setup and have it completed once and for all, instead of trying to kill it.
Does anyone know how to trigger it? Is it a system program?
Thanks

PS: to be clear here's an example of the program i'm referring to


That’s apart of OOBE, which is the last configuration pass of Windows Setup [oobeSystem] - only way I’m aware of to re-run OOBE is by using SysPrep to do so, however since I’ve only run SysPrep with /Generalize (which you don’t want to do), I’m unsure what changes are made to the OS with SysPrep /oobe

(Cont’d…) Prior to running, it should be thoroughly verified what SysPrep does when not Generalizing (e.g. Generalize deletes all user accounts and their user data). I’m unsure if a Registry value is set to cause that specific part of OOBE to launch after the fact once OOBE has been exited, then immediately close from an unknown error. If it’s a Registry key doing so, that has to be addressed manually, as the following will not fix it, but if it’s due to some other kind of system file corruption, try Steps 1 - 6 (excl. Step 3)

isn't oobe also an executable? is there any difference from sysprep?

AFAIK, no: where is oobe.exe supposed to reside? OOBE is accessed either from going through the configuration phases of Windows Setup to get to the seventh and final pass oobeSystem, or via SysPrep.

i was wrong, the file name i remembered incorrectly was msoobe.exe. still, don't know what it is for
